# Mostrar el valor long double con printf() (MINGW)

Tags: c, gcc, printf

tengo problema mostrando un valor long double con printf. He creado un programa para aproximar el valor de PI con el método de Montecarlo. A la hora de mostrar los valores aleatorios enteros para los puntos se muestran correctamente, pero al retornar el valor de tipo `long double` no se muestra por pantalla, he intentado usar dentro de la función printf: "%Lf", "%lf", "%f", "%Le", "%LF", "%LG", ... obteniendo el mismo resultado, nada. Adjunto el código correspondiente y la salida del programa.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define RADIO 20
#define SIZE 100
#define ABS(n) n ? n > 0: -n;

typedef struct Point {
    int x,y;
} Point;

Point *createPoint(double, double);
int randInt(int n);
double distanceBetweenPoints(Point *point);
long double get_Almost_PI();
void showPoint(Point *);

int main() {

    long double _PI_ = get_Almost_PI();
    printf("Aproximating PI: %Lf", _PI_);
    return 0;
}

long double get_Almost_PI() {

    Point *points[SIZE];
    // reserve the memory and create the points
    printf("Creating the points...\n");
    for (int i=0; i<SIZE; i++) {
        float x = randInt(RADIO);
        float y = randInt(RADIO);
        points[i] = createPoint(x, y);
        showPoint(points[i]);
    }

    // calculating Pi....
    printf("Calculating...\n");
    long double _pi = 0;
    int rect = 0, circle = 0, counter = 0;
    while(counter < SIZE) {
        distanceBetweenPoints(points[counter++]) < RADIO ? circle++ : rect++;
        _pi = 4 * (circle/rect);
    }

    printf("%Lf", _pi);
    return _pi;
}

void showPoint(Point *point) {
    printf("(%d, %d)\n", point->x, point->y);
}

Point *createPoint(double x, double y) {
    Point *p = (Point *) malloc(sizeof(Point));
    p->x = x;
    p->y = y;
    return p;
}

double distanceBetweenPoints(Point *point) {
    // Pitagoras d = (x^2 + y^2)^(1/2)
    return sqrt(point->x*point->x + point->y*point->y);
}

int randInt(int n) {
    // return int values in the range (n, m) 
    int a = rand() % (n+n);
    return a < n ? a : -a+n;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver muestra el mensaje "Calculating..." pero los próximos impresiones por pantalla son ignorados, incluyendo el valor que intento aproximar. Cabe destacar, que uso MinGW en Windows 10, Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estamos dividiendo entre cero, revisa cuidadosamente el siguiente fragmento de código, y asegurate de que rect no es nunca cero:

```
int rect = 0, circle = 0, counter = 0;
    while(counter < SIZE) {
        distanceBetweenPoints(points[counter++]) < RADIO ? circle++ : rect++;
        _pi = 4 * (circle/rect);
    }
```

Comment: Tienes razón, al  no tomar esa precaución no me arrojaba valores. Nunca me había pasado hacer la división, imaginaba que había algún por parte del compilador pero no y no lo sabía, me fue de mucha ayuda, gracias

Comment: No conozco el compilador que usar, pero es raro que no te salte al menos un warning, de todas formas, siempre es bueno tomar algunas precauciones con operaciones matemáticas en el programa.